# Why Flutter intl plugin keeps generating wrong files even if proper template provided?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, flutter-intl

Followed the tutorial from [Internationalizing Flutter apps](https://docs.flutter.dev/ui/accessibility-and-localization/internationalization) only to discover that once
Android Studio (Giraffe|2022.3.1 Patch1)'s Flutter Int plugin was initialized it will keep generating same file `intl_en.arb` inside the `l10n` folder even if the `l10n.yaml` file had a different template.

The `l10n` folder ends up looking like this (note the unwanted `intl_en.arb` file):

[image]

l10.yaml's content is:

```yaml
arb-dir: lib/l10n
template-arb-file: app_en.arb
output-localization-file: app_localizations.dart
```

The only solution I found was to go to `pubspec.yaml` file and disable *flutter_intl* option like this:

```yaml
flutter_intl:
  enabled: false
```

but after this I have to regenerate the translation, **every time I do a change in .arb file** with next command:

```bash
flutter gen-l10n
```

For now it's kinda ok but I wonder where the problem comes from?

Comment: Have you fount a solution to this? I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I could solve this problem by deactivating `flutter_intl` in the `pubspec.yaml`

```yaml
flutter_intl:
    enabled: false
```

Then rename all of my arb files to `intl_en.arb` and in `l10n.yaml` set the name of the template file to `intl_en.arb`.

```yaml
template-arb-file: intl_en.arb
```

Lastly reactivate `flutter_intl` again

```yaml
flutter_intl:
    enabled: true
```